# Trying to read data from a string of identifiers to create binary variables in Python

Tags: python

Trying to read data from a string of identifiers to create binary variables

```
df_skills =           name           Skills         
            0      Joe         ,,skill1,,skill2,,skill3,, 
            1      Sue         ,,skill1,,skill3,, 
            2      Chris       ,,skill3,, 
            3      Sandy       ,,skill2,,skill3,, 
            4      Julia       ,,skill2,,
```

Trying to convert Skills to a set of binaries such that

```
df_skills =           name     Skill1   Skill2   Skill3        
            0      Joe            1        1        1
            1      Sue            1        0        1
            2      Chris          0        0        1
            3      Sandy          0        1        1
            4      Julia          0        1        0
```

Code so far focusing on skill1:

```
for skill_list in df_skills["Skills"]: 
    if "skill1" in skill_list:
        df_skills["skill1"] = 1
    else:
        df_skills["skill1"] = 0

print(df_skills)

df_skills =           name     Skill1          
            0      Joe            0       
            1      Sue            0       
            2      Chris          0       
            3      Sandy          0        
            4      Julia          0
```

I can't get it to recognize "skill1". Binary is always 0. How can I get it to recognize when "skill1" is present?

Comment: are you missing out `"` marks ?. Try to provide what your df_skills is as an input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get it to recognize when "skill1" is present?

i do this:

```
string = '''          name           Skills         
            0      Joe         ,,skill1,,skill2,,skill3,, 
            1      Sue         ,,skill1,,skill3,, 
            2      Chris       ,,skill3,, 
            3      Sandy       ,,skill2,,skill3,, 
            4      Julia       ,,skill2,,'''

 skill1=list()
 skill2=list()
 skill3=list()


string = string.split('\n')
for i in string:
    skill1.append(i.count('skill1')) # counting skill1 in each line and save it to skill1 list

for i in sting:
    skill2.append(i.count('skill2'))

for i in sting:
    skill3.append(i.count('skill3'))
```

now you have all skill1 , skill2 , skill3 count in each line so you can add them to your string

ex:

```
for i in range(1,len(string)): 
    print str(skill1[i])+'\n'
```

output:

```
1    

1   

0   

0   

0
```